# incrementally rank pandas dataframe subject to other boolean dataframe in panel

Tags: python, pandas, nan, rank

I have two pandas dataframes in a panel and would like to create a third df that ranks the first df (by row) but only include those where the corresponding element of the second df is True.  Some sample data to illustrate:

```
p['x']             
                   A         B         C         D         E
2015-12-31  0.957941 -0.686432  1.087717  1.363008 -1.528369
2016-01-31  0.079616  0.524744  1.675234  0.665511  0.023160
2016-02-29 -0.300144 -0.705346 -0.141015  1.341883  0.855853
2016-03-31  0.435728  1.046326 -0.422501  0.536986 -0.656256


p['y']
                A      B     C      D    E
2015-12-31   True  False  True  False  NaN
2016-01-31   True   True  True  False  NaN
2016-02-29  False   True  True   True  NaN
2016-03-31    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN
```

I have managed to do this with a few ugly hacks but still get stuck on the fact that rank won't let me use method='first' on non-numeric data.  I want to force incremental integer ranks (even if duplicates) and NaN for any cell that didn't have True in the boolean df.

Output should be of the form:

```
              A    B    C    D   E
2015-12-31  2.0  NaN  1.0  NaN NaN
2016-01-31  3.0  2.0  1.0  NaN NaN
2016-02-29  NaN  3.0  2.0  1.0 NaN
2016-03-31  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
```

My hacked attempt is below.  It works, although there should clearly be a better way to replace false with NaN.  However it doesn't work once I add method='first' and this is necessary as I may have instances of duplicated values.

```
# I first had to hack a replacement of False with NaN.
# np.nan did not evaluate correctly
# I wasn't sure how else to specify pandas NaN
rank=p['Z'].replace(False,p['Z'].iloc[3,0])

# eliminate the elements without a corresponding True
rank=rank*p['X']

# then this works
p['rank'] = rank.rank(axis=1, ascending=False)

# but this doesn't
p['rank'] = rank.rank(axis=1, ascending=False, method='first')
```

Any help would be much appreciated!
thanks

1. List item

Comment: can you share the desired result of the third df... what is your code so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pd.DataFrame(np.where(p['y'] == True, p['x'], np.nan),
             p.major_axis, p.minor_axis).rank(1, ascending=False)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks very much, this does the job once I add method='first' to the rank parameters.  For some reason the 'first' parameter wouldn't work with my (ugly) implementation.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: @piRSquared I first think you can omit `=True`,  `np.where(p['y'], p['x'], np.nan)`, but it fill NaN ;), so this cannot be removed.

Comment: @jezrael I tried that.  for example here is `np.where(p['y'], p['x'], np.nan)[-1, :]` = `array([ 0.435728,  1.046326, -0.422501,  0.536986, -0.656256])`

Comment: @jezrael or  a better example: `np.where(np.nan, 1, 0)`